# No CSS rendering in react components

Tags: css, reactjs, rendering

What I have is a component as well as a style sheet located in the same folder. My import is correct and there are also no compile errors, however when the css information isnt being rendered at all in my webUI. What could be the issue?

The component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useTable } from "react-table";
import { CSVLink } from "react-csv";
import "./employee.css";


const columns = [
//...
    ]


function Employee({employeeData}) {

//...

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                  <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Employee;
```

The stylesheet:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
 
table th, table td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
 
table th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell just with your code. What happens? Did you try inspecting your table and seeing if the styles are applied?

Comment: where can I inspect that - sorry I am relatively new to web development. Well definitely in the developer tools, but then ...

Comment: So, if you right-click the table and click Inspect in Chrome, you'll see the DevTools open and in the styles section, there may be the styles you added, or not.

Comment: wenn I insepct the elements, I see no css added

Comment: please share your react-table version. and is this project created by creact-react-app?

Comment: "react-table": "^7.8.0", and it more or less created with create-react-app. Due to proxy reasons this command didnt work but I found a workaround to manually set up the same...

Comment: If the page you're seeing uses the code you posted, and imported the correct CSS file, it should work. Maybe post it in codesandbox and we can take another look.

Comment: is the css stylesheet also suppossed to appear in the head of the html doc??

Comment: "is the css stylesheet also supposed to appear in the head of the html doc?" Yes, for sure. If it's not there, then there's something wrong with how the page is being constructed.

Comment: SOLVED: Styled components (the library) is being used in my project and with that it works. Maybe this is overwriting normal css templates...

Comment: It could be a specificity issue, but you said that styles are not applied at all, so maybe it's not it